# Cannot store a value in local storage

Tags: javascript, html, jsonp, local-storage

I have fetched a list of items from web service, now i want to store the item_name on which I have clicked. I cannot store that item name, if its "bread butter" , it stores only "bread".
What shall i do now?

```
<script>
var sub_catidall = [];
var sub_catnameall = [];

function selected_index(sub_cat_name_all) {
    alert("selected sub category" + sub_cat_name_all);
    //window.localStorage.setItem("current_sub_id_all",sub_cat_id_all);
    window.localStorage.setItem("DishName", sub_cat_name_all);
    window.open("MenuDetails.html", "_self");
}

function jsondata(data) {
    var parsedata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    var sub_category = parsedata["Item List"];

    for (var i = 0; i < sub_category.length; i++) {
        var sub_menuall = sub_category[i];
        sub_catidall = sub_menuall['menuItemId'];
        sub_catnameall = sub_menuall['menuItemName'];
        //alert(sub_catnameall);

        var id = document.createElement("table");

        if ((i % 2) == 0) {
            id.innerHTML += '<br><td><a href="#" id=' + sub_catnameall + ' onclick="selected_index(this.id)"><strong><font face="DEVROYE">' + sub_menuall['menuItemName'] + '</a></td></strong>';
            document.getElementById("block_left").appendChild(id);

        } else {
            id.innerHTML += '<br><tr><td><a href="#" id=' + sub_catnameall + ' onclick="selected_index(this.id)"><strong><font face="DEVROYE">' + sub_menuall['menuItemName'] + '</a></td></strong>';
            document.getElementById("block_right").appendChild(id);
        }
    }
}

jsonp("http://remoteaddress/hotelTab/menuitem.php?callback=jsondata&mCatId=" + window.localStorage.getItem('current_id') + "&menuCategoryId=" + window.localStorage.getItem('current_sub_id'));
</script>
```

Comment: Why did you post another copy of question rather than improve this one? [copy post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22004591/how-to-save-data-with-white-spaces-in-local-storage-using-javascript-in-html5)

Comment: Because then I searched a lot on storing white spaces in local storage, but did not get satisfactory answer. So I thought I would get any suggestion about storage of white spaces.

Comment: But you gave no new information, in fact you gave less until I asked you for it.

Answer (score 1):

[DOM Storage Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)

Example

```
var string = 'Bread Butter';

localStorage.setItem("DishName", string);

alert(localStorage.getItem('DishName'));
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/EZBaL/)

Answer (score 0):

I use [Amplifyjs store](http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/) library to access local storage.
It's simple to use/understand, works really well and it's cross browser (mobile browser as well)

Hope this Helps