# How to save data with white spaces in local storage using javascript in html5?

Tags: javascript, html, jsonp, local-storage

Data is fetched from web service in variable. How to store the data with white spaces ex:"Bread Butter" in the local storage?

In the function selected_index I have passed the item_name of the clicked item.
It leaves the word after space and does not store it.

This is my code.

```
<script>
var sub_catidall = [];
var sub_catnameall = [];

function selected_index(sub_cat_name_all) {
    alert("selected sub category" + sub_cat_name_all);
    //window.localStorage.setItem("current_sub_id_all",sub_cat_id_all);
    window.localStorage.setItem("DishName", sub_cat_name_all);
    window.open("MenuDetails.html", "_self");
}

function jsondata(data) {
    var parsedata = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
    var sub_category = parsedata["Item List"];

    for (var i = 0; i < sub_category.length; i++) {
        var sub_menuall = sub_category[i];
        sub_catidall = sub_menuall['menuItemId'];
        sub_catnameall = sub_menuall['menuItemName'];
        //alert(sub_catnameall);

        var id = document.createElement("table");

        if ((i % 2) == 0) {
            id.innerHTML += '<br><td><a href="#" id=' + sub_catnameall + ' onclick="selected_index(this.id)"><strong><font face="DEVROYE">' + sub_menuall['menuItemName'] + '</a></td></strong>';
            document.getElementById("block_left").appendChild(id);

        } else {
            id.innerHTML += '<br><tr><td><a href="#" id=' + sub_catnameall + ' onclick="selected_index(this.id)"><strong><font face="DEVROYE">' + sub_menuall['menuItemName'] + '</a></td></strong>';
            document.getElementById("block_right").appendChild(id);
        }
    }
}

jsonp("http://remoteaddress/hotelTab/menuitem.php?callback=jsondata&mCatId=" + window.localStorage.getItem('current_id') + "&menuCategoryId=" + window.localStorage.getItem('current_sub_id'));
</script>
```

Comment: I made a function and passed the name of the item on which we click to that function. And I have to store that item name in local storage. I used-  window.localStorage.setItem("DishName",sub_cat_name_all);        Now, if the item name is "Bread Butter", it stores only "Bread" in local storage. I have posted whole code in previous question.Please help with your suggestion.

Comment: Will you show us the code that you have attempted and have problems with?

Comment: I have posted the code in the post.

Comment: Do you have a canned sample of the JSON data? And can you put it all together in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to demonstrate?

Comment: Am sorry, I cannot put it up.

Answer (score 0):

[DOM Storage Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)

Example

```
var string = 'Bread Butter';

localStorage.setItem("DishName", string);

alert(localStorage.getItem('DishName'));
```

On [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/EZBaL/)